# How to bookmark an automatically redirecting link on the Android?

Tags: browser, bookmarks

I am on page_1. There is a link_1 to page_2 that redirects to a random URL page_x. I cannot go to page_2 because I will not see its URL in the address bar (it redirects to page_x)

I want to bookmark link_1. On a non-mobile browser, I would right click link_1 and bookmark it.

I am using the pre-installed "Internet" browser that comes with the Android. How do I bookmark link_1 on Android?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I entirely understood the scenario you're describing, but a similar function to right-click->bookmark on Android would be to do a long press on the link, then choose Bookmark link. This should bookmark the link as it exists on the page, regardless of where it eventually sends you.

Comment: I don't see that option on 3.1 Honeycomb's browser.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a "Bookmark Link" option on 3.1 Honeycomb's browser. An alternative would be to:

1. Copy the URL link by long pressing the link you need to bookmark and choose "Copy link URL"
2. Create a new bookmark by clicking on the star on the location bar on any page
3. Replace the label and location in the new bookmark options with the URL you just copied and the title of the page you need to bookmark